# Jquery .hover function fade in and out issue

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with this hover.
When the child item inside is clicked, the entire menu fades out, then back in.

```
$('.sc_menuwrap').hover(function(){
                $('.sc_menuwrap').stop().fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This sets the opacity to 100% on hover
            },function(){
                $('.sc_menuwrap').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0); // This sets the opacity back to 60% on mouseout
            });
```

You can see the working example here: http://dluxstudios.com/11 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.sc_menuwrap').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
        },function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0);
 });
```

Try this, must work.

Comment: No change. You're only using the THIS object, which is not really any different than my literal reference to my objects class name. But thanks!

Comment: No change. Thanks... might be a good idea to have people check my actual link out...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `stop(true, true)`